# Minimizing a KS function

Tags: solver, convex-optimization, algorithms

For convex functions $f_i, \ i \in I$, the KS function is defined as the following for any $\rho > 0$:

$$KS[\{ f_i \}_{i \in I}](x):= (1/ \rho) \ln \left[ \sum_{i \in I} \exp(\rho f_i(x)) \right].$$

It can be shown that the KS function is convex and smooth.

I am wondering, which algorithm should I be using to minimize $KS[\{ f_i \}_{i \in I}]$ over some 'easy' constraints such as convex quadratic constraints? Is there an optimization solver that would solve this problem easily? I imagine this depends on the functions $f_i$, so as a starting point, I am happy with them being convex quadratic or geometric functions.

Answer (score 2):

I see two interesting options, the first one is a generic NLP solver which might use an interior point (IPOPT) or an SQP ([List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_quadratic_programming#Implementations)) approach. The other options is that according to my vague (and maybe wrong) understanding of conic programming that conic programming might be an interesting approach. the $\ln$ and $\exp$ terms could be model as exponential cones while convex quadratic constraints could be expressed in a power cone. As for how far your f can be modeled in that framework i can't tell, just if it is non-convex then conic programming will not work and you have to rely on a generic NLP solver, which is no longer guaranteed to find a global optimum either. In this case you have to look into global NLP solvers and best ask a separate question.

For conic problem [Mosek](https://www.mosek.com/) has a solver. However i would recommend using the JuMP modeling language as that can create problems that can be called by many solvers including free solvers. For an introduction have a look into [this publication](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.01136).

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! I know how to formulate log-sum-exp-linear-terms function as an exponential conic function, but I was also struggling with the "$f_i$" terms as you also raised a concern for. I will keep an open mind!

Answer (score 1):

Some NLP solvers may be sensitive to how the model is formulated/presented,
so you may wish to try alternative formulations for each NLP solver you try.
At one extreme, the "atomic" formulation is:

```
  minimize (1/rho)*LN( w);
   w = sum( i: u_i);
   For each i:
    { u_i = exp( v_i);
      v_i = rho*f_i(x_i);
    };
```

So if early in the optimization iterations the solver decides that
certain of the `x_i` should be at a bound, the solver can avoid
recomputing the associated `f_i(x_i)` and `exp( v_i)`.